# $e^{(A+B)} = e^Ae^Be^{[A,B]}$ for non commuting A and B?

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory

For non commuting A and B, and the derivative of $[A,B] = 0$. Is it true that/how to prove that 
$e^{(A+B)} = e^Ae^Be^{[A,B]}$

If not, what is the expression according to [Wikipedia's article on the Baker–Campbell–Hausdorff formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula)

Comment: Presumably you prove / disprove it by expanding the exponential function into its power series representation, and then comparing terms of equal degrees.

Comment: Surely $[A,B] = 0$ means that $A,B$ commute?

Comment: @copper.hat Didn't he say "the derivative of $[A, B]$"?

Comment: @Arthur: Yes, I assumed it just meant the commutator was zero, otherwise I am not sure what the derivative of $[A, B]$ means.

Comment: @copper.hat I agree that that seems strange. Are the operators $A$ and $B$ time-dependant or something? I dunno.

Comment: Well, if the derivative of $(A,B) \mapsto [A,B]$ is zero, then $A,B$ commute with every matrix and hence are multiplies of the identity (and hence commute).

Comment: Yes it is derivative.

Comment: Derivative with respect to what?

Comment: Please edit the question to fix it: as it stands, it makes no sense.

Comment: One might speculate that the right-hand side is a miscopy of $e^A e^B e^{[A,B]}$ or something similar. At least the "type checking" would be ok then.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what the OP means by "the derivative of $[A,B] = 0$", but the equation
$$e^{A+B} = e^A e^B [A,B]$$
is certainly not on.  This would imply in particular that $[A,B]$ has determinant $1$, which is destroyed by scaling of $A$ or $B$.  It's also false in a limit as, say, $B$ approaches something that commutes with $A$.